# Read file in node is not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I use the following code to read json files from my node application folder.
I've folder with json files and I want to read the content with the following code
the proj built like following

```
myproj
  folder1
     file1
  jsonFiles
    json1.json
```

now from file1 I want to get json1,I try with the following which doesnt work..any idea?

```
 glob("jsonFiles/*.json", function(err, files) { 

            files.forEach(function(file) {
                fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                 console.log("im here")
```

Im not able to reach the "im here" in the console,what it can be ?
when I put Break-point I able to see get to  fs.readFile but in the next line it doesnt stops and I dont get any error...
UPD

in debug I see in **file** `fs.readFile(file, 'utf8'`, the following path:`jsonFiles/json1.json`

Comment: First, `files.forEach` is synchronous and you're calling an async method inside it. It won't work the way you expect. Second: it's `consloe.log` in your code or it's just a typo in the code snippet?

Comment: And you should also log the `err` to see what's going on.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros -Thanks this is typo :) but what should I do to make it work? I put if(err) instead of the err but I dont get any error since its not jumping to the next line(in debug mode)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine:

```
$ touch 1 2 3

$ cat > app.js
var fs = require('fs');
var files = ['1', '2', '3'];
files.forEach(function(file) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
     console.log("im here");
    });
});
^D

$ nodejs app.js
im here
im here
im here
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not helping since I try to do it on files inside my project...

Comment: in debug I see in file fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', the following path:jsonFiles/json1.json

Comment: You can `mkdir jsonFiles`, `touch jsonFiles/json{1,2,3}.json` and replace the files `files` array in the *.js file with `[ 'jsonFiles/json1.json' ...` and it still works. Your problem is most likely in that that glob doesn't call you back with the `files` you expect. Log it to see what `files` you're getting before you call forEach on it.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean with mkdir jsonFiles, touch jsonFiles/json{1,2,3}.json can you provide example in your answer?

Comment: That's just basic command lines stuff for creating the directory and the files that the node script will try to read from.

Comment: I think that this is related to glob I accept your answer and I've additional question now maybe you can help :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386539/how-to-use-code-in-node-js-just-one-time-for-application