# Call to modules in specific order in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, bluebird

I've used the following code to call two modules, but the invoke action is called before the validate file (I saw in debug). What I should do to verify that `validateFile` is called before `appHandler.invokeAction`? Should I use a promise?

```
var validator = require('../uti/valid').validateFile();
var appHandler = require('../contr/Handler');
appHandler.invokeAction(req, res);
```

Update

this is the validate file code

```
var called = false;
var glob = require('glob'),
    fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {

    validateFile: function () {

        glob("myfolder/*.json", function (err, files) {
            var stack = [];
            files.forEach(function (file) {
                fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) { // Read each file
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("cannot read the file", err);
                    }
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    obj.action.forEach(function (crud) {
                        for (var k in crud) {
                            if (_inArray(crud[k].path, stack)) {

                                console.log("duplicate founded!" + crud[k].path);

                                break;
                            }
                            stack.push(crud[k].path);
                        }
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: It totally depends on the implementation of `validateFile`. Does it return a promise ? Does it accept a callback as parameter ? Answer that and you answer your question.

Comment: @DenysSéguret - I can share the validate file please see my update

Comment: So the point is that `fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) { // Read each file` this is `async` your `validateFile` should alter to accept a callback, and call it at the last of `fs.readFile`'s success callback.

Comment: @so how can I do the validations before I do the all process ? I mean the invokeAction function,there is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `glob` and `fs.readFile` are async functions and appHandler.invokeAction is invoked during i/o from disk.

Promise is a good solution to solve this but an old school callback could do the job.

```
validator.validateFile().then(function() {
  appHandler.invokeAction(req, res);
});
```

and for validate

```
var Promise = require("bluebird"), // not required if you are using iojs or running node with `--harmony`
    glob = require('mz/glob'),
    fs = require('mz/fs');

module.exports = {
  validateFile: function () {
    return glob("myfolder/*.json").then(function(files) {
      return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
        // will return an array of promises, if any of them
        // is rejected, validateFile promise will be rejected
        return fs.readFile(file).then(function (content) {
          // throw new Error(''); if content is not valid
        });
      }));
    })
  }
};
```

If you want working with promise [mz](https://github.com/normalize/mz) could help :)

Comment: I like this, promise seems much more beautiful than callback way, but I can't get it much, is there any good tutorials for promise?

Comment: Thanks should I use it instead of bluebird,it is better ? thanks in advance!

Comment: Check if the version of nodejs you are using support it, iojs support it from 1.0. From Mozilla Developper Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @jsan - voted up! can you please provide example how to use it with bluebird

Comment: thanks jsan,why I need the blue bird and mz?I cannot do it with bulebird only?if yes can you provide example?thanks in advance sir!

Comment: mz is an helper to get promise from native node api, it is just more convenient if you use promises. You could do it without mz by using promise constructor and call `resolve` at the end of the validation (don't forget to call `reject` on other cases or your promise will never be closed). please don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As the `fs.fileRead` is `async`, you should put the code that you want to execute after `validateFile` to its `callback`.

The origin could be:

```
var validator = require('../uti/valid').validateFile();
var appHandler = require('../contr/Handler');
// create a new function that when execute, will call appHandler.invokeAction with req and res given to its arguments.
validator.validateFile(appHandler.invokeAction.bind(null, req, res));
```

The validator part should be:

```
var called = false;
var glob = require('glob'),
    fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    validateFile: function (callback) {

        glob("myfolder/*.json", function (err, files) {
            var stack = [];
            // Use it to decide whether all files processed or not.
            var filesToLoad = files.length;
            files.forEach(function (file) {
                fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) { // Read each file
                    --filesToLoad;
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("cannot read the file", err);
                        // If the invoke action doesn't depend on the result. You may want to call it here too.
                    }
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    obj.action.forEach(function (crud) {
                        for (var k in crud) {
                            if (_inArray(crud[k].path, stack)) {

                                console.log("duplicate founded!" + crud[k].path);

                                break;
                            }
                            stack.push(crud[k].path);
                        }
                    })

                    // Only called the callback after all files processed.
                    if (filesToLoad === 0) {
                      callback();
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Edit: Thanks for Bergi's remind that there's the files are an array and you have to call the callback when all files is processed, so we have to further use a variable to decide how many files are not processed yet.

Comment: Thanks do you think that this is better than promise ?Thanks a lot

Comment: I think if you're not familiar with promise, then this is better for understanding, but if you have play with promise some time. promise's way seems more elegant to me, IMO.

Comment: You mustn't call `callback` from a loop.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the notification, changed code to handle that, mind take a look if its valid now?

Comment: Thanks, looks good now (except maybe for error handling which could be improved). Now it's even more obvious why promises are the better solution :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I agree, is there some good teachings you would provide? I want to learn more about that, but not sure where to get a good start. Thanks in advance. (P.S: The error handling part I just keep the same with OP, as he may have reasons about why he write like that.)